# How to remove or capture the event of iOS date picker clear button?

Tags: html, ios, webview, safari, wkwebview

I have a html Date input showed inside webView of an iOS app. I want to remove the Clear button that comes beside the Done button in native date picker as shown in the image below. There are few other similar questions but no one has given a proper solution for this. Capturing the clear button event also can help. Thanks.
                                             [image]

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No. Couldn't find any answer for this.